# Inject or filter collection to get only ouput channels

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

if I use

```
@Autowired
List<MessageChannel> messageChannels;
```

I get all channels.
The channels are inputs, but also outputs.
How can I get only `outputs` channels here?

Class of this object is `org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel`

I want to get rid of objects that are marked as `@Input` that are class
`instanceof org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel`

Each object of `messageChannels` gives:

```
object instanceof org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel = true
object instanceof org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel = true
```

I do not want to filter them by `name`.

Answer (score 0):

The following applies to `spring-cloud-stream` only:

You cannot filter them with `@Autowired` but if you inject `List<DirectWithAttributesChannel>` you can then determine the channel type using `getAttribute("type")` which will be one of `Sink.INPUT` or `Source.OUTPUT`.

Comment: What do you mean by `DirectWithAttributesChannel` ? In my case I can not import it. I want to get `Source.OUTPUTs` from the whole application not just from one class.

Comment: I tested it on application with `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.SR4`

`spring-cloud-stream 1.3.3`

Comment: That version is too old; `DirectWithAttributesChannel` was added (exactly for this purpose) in 2.1. With older versions, all you can do is cast the channel to `NamedComponent` and check its name.